# Hybrid apps using NativeScript

Tags: javascript, ios, telerik, nativescript

I'm looking at NativeScript and I see a lot of potential for making app development easier. The question that I have right now is whether or now it's possible to run NativeScript on the fly. For example, is it possible to create an iOS app fully written in Objective-C and then leave an about page to NativeScript and get the script from a source in runtime and evaluate it in the app, the way JavaScript gets evaluated for each web page?

I read that NativeScript does use JIT but what I don't understand the require mechanism, how is it possible to require Node modules if you evaluate code in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native lets you do this. I'm not endorsing it as I'm evaluating solutions as well, but technically you can instantiate their bridge and manage it from existing iOS apps, they even have example repos.

Comment: But it wouldn't be on runtime though, would it? can I get a piece of JavaScript code and interpret it?

Comment: Yes it would be runtime. The big downside for me with {N} was exactly this, no obvious path of not having it take control over your app (i.e. you need greenfield projects).
In RN I don't think you can "embed" JS code in ObjC eval-style but I'd hardly believe someone would find a valid use case for that.

Comment: @blackxored can you link to those examples? I'm not able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, to some extent.   Their is no easy mechanism in NativeScript to let you start your ObjC app; and then call into NativeScript.  You can do it the opposite; start a NativeScript application and call into your own ObjC.   NativeScript is the controller of the application.

As for dynamic pages; yes this is very easy to do.  In fact I use a technique to do just this in my [NativeScript-LiveSync](http://www.github.com/NathanaelA/NativeScript-LiveSync) plugin.   All the JavaScript is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Do you know any other tool I can use for that purpose? I basically want one page of my app to be fully driven by JavaScript.

Comment: Why not just use a UIWebView; the webview page would load your local html and javascript and so then you JS would be totally in charge of doing any stuff on that page.

Comment: That's true but I want to use native UI.

Comment: Then currently the only way to do it would be to let NativeScript control the initial execution; then call into your code to take control of the the environment then run your normal app.  Once the user picks that screen you exit back into the NS code.  Then do all your cool NS stuff; then re-call back into your application when they exit the NS window.    It would be a pain to do -- but technically it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael I'm thinking maybe I can create a framework that is basically my app written in ObjC, all my main view controllers, static libs I'm using, etc. Then inject it to my NativeScript app and then present the main view controller in the framework immediately on start up. Is this something I can do? It does sound sketchy and extremely painful but hey it's a solution:)